# Не сохраняет файл при запуске программы не из терминала (golang)

Tags: linux, golang

Почему не сохраняет файл в случаи если запускаю через [upstart](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) или [nohup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) ?
В случаи когда запускаю через go run или просто исполняемый файл через ./file &
все отлично сохраняет. 
И nohup когда из терминала запускаю также отрабатывает, а вот когда стартует система например в файле /etc/rc.local, процесс есть, а файл не создается.
Просветите пожалуйста, что же не так..

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "io"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  f, err := os.OpenFile("path/file.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
  if err != nil {
    // error
    return
  }
  defer f.Close()
  r := strings.NewReader("string\n")
  if _, err := io.Copy(f, r); err != nil {
    // error
    return
  }
  f.Close()
}
```

Comment: Потому что запускается в другой текущей папке.

Comment: Используйте полные пути. Смотрите этот пример https://gist.github.com/ArxdSilva/4f73d6b89c9eac93d4ac887521121120 для получения текущей папки в которой содержится бинарный файл.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, не думал что из такой мелочи как абсолютный путь, могут быть такие проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при старте из /etc/rc.local у вас получается другая рабочая папка по умолчанию, вероятно корневая - /
и файл path/file.txt ищется от корня, т.е. /path/file.txt. Папки path у вас в корне скорее всего нет, поэтому программа и отваливается с ошибкой.

Для обхода этой проблемы нужно использовать абсолютные пути (самый простой и очевидный способ), либо при старте программы менять рабочую папку чтобы работать с относительными путями внутри неё.